# How to pass arguments when using apply in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, arguments, parameter-passing, apply

I want to `apply` a function along a column, eg `coco.convert`, and pass to it, along with the value in the row, the argument `to = 'ISO3'`.

```
df['alpha-3'] = df['Country'].apply(coco.convert('ISO3'))
```

misses 1 positional argument:

```
TypeError: convert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'names'
```

but

```
df['alpha-3'] = df['Country'].apply(coco.convert)
```

works fine (I assume it uses default values).

How do I pass the positional argument here?

Also, what exactly is happening here - can someone explain a little how the function is passed to `apply`?

Comment: "can someone explain a little how the function is passed to apply?" What exactly do you not understand? A function is just an object, like any other, `int`, `list`, `dict` etc. it works exactly the same way

Comment: Anyway, did you [read the documentation for the series `.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method? Anything relevant about how to pass additional arguments?

Comment: Note, `.apply(coco.convert('ISO3'))` would not work the way you want it to even without the TypeError, it *calls* the function, `coco.convert("ISO3")` and passes the *result* of that to `.apply`, but `.apply` expects a function. (Note, this *might* work if coco.convert *returned a function* itself, but that is not what you seem to describe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most normal way to solve this would be to use the `**kwds` argument for `.apply` which are covered in the [apply documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). Basically you can just pass any other named arguments to .apply() and it uses them with the passed function.

```py
df['alpha-3'] = df['Country'].apply(coco.convert, to='ISO3')
```

An alternative way to do it would be to define your own new function with the arguments pre-passed such as below.

```py
def my_fun(x):
    return coco.convert(names = x, to = 'ISO3')

df['alpha-3'] = df['Country'].apply(my_fun)
```

To your other about how .apply works...

1. Take the column of data you give it, and loop through each element
2. For each element, feed its value into the supplied function as the *first
3. For each return of that function, convert it into another Pandas series.

Comment: Thank you, that's the explanation I was looking for, had some trouble understanding the documentation! Much appreciated.